# How can I find family of non-isomorphic graphs with specific properties?

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory

I asked this question:
[How to find non-isomorphic graphs with specific orders?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381544/how-to-find-non-isomorphic-graphs-with-specific-orders/381596#381596)

Two new questions have arisen for me.

I have a graph, $G$, with $2n$ vertices. It has one connected component of order $2n-1$ and an isolated vertex. $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2\geq \ldots \geq \lambda_{2n}$ are the eigenvalues of $G$. I have some bounds for them.
$$\lambda_1=2n-3,\\
 0\leq \lambda_2\leq 1,\\
 -1\leq \lambda_i\leq \frac{1}{2}, \ \ \ 3\leq i \leq n+1,\\
 -3\leq \lambda_{n+2}\leq -1,\\
 -3\leq \lambda_i\leq \frac{-3}{2},\ \ \ n+ 3\leq i \leq 2n.$$
Also the maximum degree of this graph is $2n-2$.
Is there any family graphs with these properties?

My second question:

Let $G$ be a connected graph with $2n$ vertices, $2n−3≤λ_1≤Δ≤2n−2$, $Δ$ is the maximum degree of the graph $G$ and other conditions for its eigenvalues are as same as above.
I found One family graph with these properties: $(K_{2,\ldots,2}\nabla K_1).K2$.

$K_{2,\ldots,2}$ and $K_2$ are a multipartite graph with $n-1$ parts of size 2 and a complete graph, respectively.
$K_{2,\ldots,2}\nabla K_1$ is join of each vertex of
$K_{2,\ldots,2}$  with one isolated vertex,e.g. $K_1$.

$(K_{2,\ldots,2} \nabla K_1).K2$, is
the coalescence of $K_2$ with
$K_{2,\ldots,2} \nabla K_1$
with its vertex of maximum degree as distinguished vertex.The coalescence $G.H$ is obtained by the disjoint union of two graphs $G$ and $H$ by identifying a vertex $u$ of $G$ with a vertex $v$ of $H$.

How can i find another family graphs with these properties for $6\leq n \leq 10$ ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your second question, you require $2n-2 \leqslant 2n-3$ which may be tricky.

Comment: @Royle Gordon Thank you. I edited it.